Incorrect duration for youtube video when using youtube v3 api
I am fetching a video using official Youtube data API, and through that I am getting the response in the following format,
contentDetails: {
    ​​​
    definition: "hd",
    ​​​
    dimension: "2d",
    ​​​
    duration: "PT9M36S",
    ​​​
    licensedContent: true,
    ​​​
    projection: "rectangular",
    ​​​​​
}

This duration is incorrect since the video itself is one second short, i.e. of 9 minute 35 second.
This happened in each of the 6 video that I uploaded. And while viewing the embedded video, the duration fluctuate by 1 second back and forth. This prevents us from tracking user progress of the given video. Though we have solved it using some workaround, but the issue still exists and unaddressed, so dropping the question here.
If anyone can tell me why this might happens and if the issue as direct as it seems why it isn't being corrected, since this seems, prima facie, to be very minor issue on the backend, which can be easily fix.
Also, the only official place to report any issue with API seems to be stackoverflow as stated by them, but some similar question on stackoverflow itself doesn't have official addressal or response from google's team. Hope it can be resolved through this post.
Steps to recreate the issue:

Get a Youtube api key
Fetch video content details from youtube api using the below command
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=${youtubeVideoId}&key=${youtubeApiKey}&part=snippet,contentDetails"

You will notice that it is one second greater than the actual video length.

May you provide an example video id having this issue? Note that Google staff does not come to Stack Overflow, at least these recent years. If you really want to possibly have a Google staff response then use their bugtracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803 (source)

It is happening for every single youtube video I uploaded for test as well as official use. For instance this one also have the same issue. And thanks for the reference I will raise this issue there too then.

The youtube api hasnt been updated in years.  your expecting to much from it.

I’m voting to close this question because its probably a bug in the api author should report the bug.

This prevents us from tracking user progress of the given video. you have a one second precision in your tracking? Honestly depending on how you round the video duration (floor, ceil or round) you may end up with 2 durations. Both YouTube UI and YouTube Data API v3 do not seem to precise what rounding they use... It seems that the duration even depends on the stream (yt-dlp the video you mentioned and then ffprobe mentions 2:09.432 for vp9 and 2:09.461 for opus) but maybe this is an yt-dlp artifact.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo  Yeah I guess I was expecting too much. But it's an existing issue and it is a public API, so though it should be here in public domain. Anyway, I've reported this issue on there official issue tracker as suggested by Benjamin, so it's fine you can close this question. Now it's upto them to resolve it, if they got time.

@BenjaminLoison Yeah, we do need that 1 second precision specific to our application, but we have used a workaround for this, and now it's not that big of a deal for me. And your analysis does seems to point that the issue is somewhere in rounding off the millisecond precision. And if it is so it should be a simple fix Let's wait and see. Hopefully Google's dev will fix this issue if they come across it.
